# ZendOptimizer, ZendGuard, IonCube and sourceguardian on Windows Plesk

Tags: windows, plesk, ioncube

I have Plesk 11.5 installed on Windows server 2008 R2.
On the Plesk installation i have 3 different versions of PHP.

PHP 5.2.17 - PHP 5.3.27 - PHP 5.4.16

**What i am trying to install is as bellow :**
On PHP 5.2.17 : Ioncube - SourceGuardian - ZendOptimizer
On PHP 5.3.27 : Ioncube - SourceGuardian - ZendGuard
On PHP 5.4.16 : Ioncube - SourceGuardian - ZendGuard

My PHP is Thread Safe so for IonCube and SourceGuardian i downloaded ts versions.
i put the corresponding .dll and .win files in ext folder for each PHP installation and then i call them in php.ini as follows :

zend_extension_ts="E:\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5[x]\ext\extension_name.dll"

where [x] is the address corresponding to each PHP version and extension_name.dll is the name of the extension (extension_name.win in case i am calling sourceguardian).

**Now here is the problem :**

On PHP 5.2.17 : IonCube works - SourceGuardian Gives 500 Internal error - ZendOptimizer Works
On PHP 5.3.27 : Nothing Works [it's like PHP does not even look at those call lines!]
On PHP 5.4.16 : Nothing Works [it's like PHP does not even look at those call lines!]

Now in each case, i have tested all available versions of those files which corresponds to my PHP version. for example for SourceGuardian i tested both x86 and x64 and VC6 versions for PHP 5.3. I Also tried putting them into their own separate folders. for example : IonCube/extension_name.dll. but it seems like PHP just does not look at what i call in there.

I Checked the phpinfo() output and i am sure that i am editing the right php.ini files.

I will be very thankful if you give me directions on solving this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your hunch is actually correct, as zend_extension_ts was removed in PHP 5.3. Use zend_extension for 5.3 and above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. i can see that php reads my lines now. ionCube is working on php 5.3 and both ioncube and ZendGuard are working on php 5.4. but still no luck with sourceGuardian ...

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as the accepted one :) If you don't actually need source guardian or any other extension then it's generally best to leave it out in the interests of keeping your system lean and minimising future upgrade tasks.